# Prove the operator given by convolution with homogeneous function $u$ maps $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: lp-spaces, distribution-theory, convolution, harmonic-analysis, homogeneous-spaces

> **Q**:Suppose that $u$ is a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function on $\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash\{0\}$ that is homogeneous of degree $-n+i \tau, \tau \in \mathbb{R} .$ Prove that the operator given by convolution with $u$ maps $L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ to $L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$.

A distribution in $\mathscr{S}^{\prime}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ is called *homogeneous of degree* $\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ if for all $\lambda>0$ and for all $\varphi \in \mathscr{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right),$ we have
$$\left\langle u, \delta^{\lambda} \varphi\right\rangle=\lambda^{-n-\gamma}\langle u, \varphi\rangle,$$
where $\delta$ is dilation.

It seems I need to prove $u*f\in L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ for all $f\in L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$, I am stuck since I have no idea how to combine translation and dilation. Sincerely thanks for your help!

Comment: What is $\delta^\lambda$? Dilation?

Comment: Possible method: Fourier transform $\hat u$ is also homogeneous of degree $-i\tau$.  Now you need to show that a product of such homogeneous function with an $L^2$ function belongs to $L^2$.

Comment: @$\delta^\lambda \phi=\phi(\lambda x)$. You mean I need to prove $\hat u \hat f \in L^2$, that sounds a good idea, I can try it, thx ^_^.